# Rails: Sum value of column on a associated table

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sum

I have a list of websites, and each website has a list of domains. I have summarized the costs per website for those domains. What I want to do next is summarize all the costs for the websites, and get one total price for all websites.

So what I have to summarize the costs:

```
<% @websites.includes(:domains).each do |website| %>
   <%= number_to_currency website.domains.sum(:costs), :locale => :nl %>
<% end %>
```

This returns:

€ 65,00 € 12,50 € 12,50 € 12,50 € 12,50 € 25,00 € 25,00 € 23.435,50 € 37,50 € 0,00 € 0,00 € 0,00 € 0,00 € 0,00 € 34,00

Now I need to find a way to summarize these sums...

Comment: Could you show your table structure and model relations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest possible solution to get sum of costs for all domains for all websites is:

```
@websites.includes(:domains).map{|website| website.domains.sum(:costs)}.sum
```

**Edit** 
If you want to get the sum of costs for all domains that you have in the database, you can use (it will generate only one SQL query):

```
Domain.all.sum(:costs)
```

Comment: `collection.map { ... }.sum` => `collection.sum { ... }`

Comment: this is not sql function, plain array method which is slow on big data massives

Answer (score 2):

A more effective way than iterating in Ruby is by selecting an aggregate in the query:

```
@websites = Website.select('websites.*, SUM(domains.cost) AS websites.domain_costs')
       .left_outer_joins(:domains)
```

This removes the need to load the domain records into memory, and DBs are much more effective at simple aggregation than Ruby anyways.

You can then access the sum by:

```
<% @websites.each do |website| %>
   <%= number_to_currency website.domain_costs, :locale => :nl %>
<% end %>
```